# Can I label a Gmail message from a popup window?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts, gmail-labels

I let Gmail run in the background, and it gives me some nice browser notifications for every received message. Clicking these opens the message in a new popup window.

[image]

I know I can trash or archive these conversations with the keyboard shortcuts, but there seems to be no way to **label** them.

Is there any? Maybe through userscripts, extensions?

Comment: What notifier are you using? From the screenshot, I have to ask, have you tried the drop down?

Comment: What do you mean by "notifier"? The drop down only allows to reply, forward, print, report fishing, etc. – no labeling.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately that’s not possible at the moment, not even through the keyboard shortcuts. That’s one feature I’d very much like, since the Chrome notifier is really handy.